# Whats the $\bigcup B$? Being $\bigcup B$ the union of all subsets (all of this empty).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So if I have $B = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$, what's the union of all this subsets?\

Comment: What are the elements of the elements of B?

Comment: They are what I say in the question @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: "Subsets" of what? Usually when you refere to a set $B$ as a "subset", you should say of what set $B$ is a subset. For example, $\{1\}$ is a subset of the natural numbers, but also a subset of the real numbers. $\bigcup B$ is just the set of all those object that belong to some set in $B$, so just put together (as Mauro ALLEGRANZA tried to hint, I think) all the elements of the elements of $B$. Also, usually when you write a set as a list of elements between brackets $\{\}$, you write each element one time. It's now really wrong to write, for example $$\{1,1\}$$ it's just superfluous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union is

$$
\emptyset \cup \{\emptyset\} \cup \{\emptyset\}=(\emptyset\cup\{\emptyset\})\cup\{\emptyset\}\underbrace{=}_{A\cup\emptyset=A}\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\emptyset\}\underbrace{=}_{A\cup A=A}\{\emptyset\}.
$$